# What DLC and unlockable items are available for Mass Effect 3 by playing other EA titles?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know you can get some free Mass Effect 3 items from the Kingdom's of Amalur demo. I was wondering, are there other titles that give you some items for use in the game?

For example; something like the Blood Armor that was shared between Dragon Age and Mass Effect 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning

*Items unlocked by playing the KoA:R demo for 45 minutes. Must be linked to your Origin account along with ME3.*
   -  **Chakram Launcher**: Assault Rifle
   -  **Reckoner Knight Armor**: Armor with bonuses to Melee and Weapon damage

## Battlefield 3

*Unlocked by having a Battlefield 3 Online Pass linked to the same Origin account as your copy of Mass Effect 3.*
  - **Battlefield 3 Pack**: A unique loadout of items usable only in Multiplayer.